# Svelte: refs undefined

Tags: svelte

I'm using [Svelte](https://svelte.technology/) (v2.7) and [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.technology/) (v0.12). According to [the docs](https://svelte.technology/guide#refs), `this.refs` should be available, but it's `undefined` for me, both in `oncreate` and custom methods.

My index.html looks like this:

```
<select id="wifi-ssid" ref="wifi-ssid">
...

<script>
    export default {
        oncreate() {
            console.log('this.refs is undefined here', this.refs);
        },
        methods: {
            getIsValid() {
                console.log('this.refs is undefined here too', this.refs);
                // ...
            },
            // ...
        }
    };
</script>
```

([Full code here](https://github.com/poshaughnessy/things-gateway-bluetooth-pwa/blob/master/routes/index.html)).

I'm presuming this isn't a bug (otherwise everyone would have run into it?) and I've got something wrong as it's my first time using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for a `ref` directive is `ref:name`, rather than `ref="name"`. It must be a valid JavaScript identifier, e.g. `<select ref:wifissid>` rather than `wifi-ssid`.

The `refs` object isn't created if no refs are declared.

Comment: Oops. Eyesight Error :-D Thanks!

Comment: This syntax is Deprecated

Comment: This is outdated now, see the other answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is deprecated, I believe the new syntax is `<select bind:this={wifissid}>`